# How do I correctly attach a tf.Print() node to my tensorflow graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

As far as I understand it, I should be able to add a print operator to my graph by doing something like this:

```
a = nn_ops.softmax(s)

a = tf.Print(a, [tf.shape(a)], message="This is shape a: ")
```

and when the graph is executed this should print the shape of `a`. However, this statement produces no output for me (I am running the seq2seq tensorflow tutorial and this softmax belongs to the attention function, so it's definitely executed).

I **do** get output if instead I do something like this:

```
ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3,4,5,6])

ts = tf.shape(ph)

tp = tf.Print(ts, [ts], message="PRINT=")

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tp)
```

However, in my real example, `sess.run()` is called in seq2seq_model.py, and if I try to do `sess.run(a)` in the attention function, tensorflow complains:

`You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'encoder0' with dtype int32`

but I don't have access to the input feed at this point in the code. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

In case you just want to know the tensor shape, often it can be inferred without running the graph. Then you do not need `tf.Print`.

For example in the second code fragment you can just use:

```
ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3,4,5,6])
print(ph.get_shape())
```

If you want to see the shape which **depends** on the input size (using `tf.shape`) or you want to see a value which also **depends** on the input, it is not possible to do without providing the input data.

For example if you train the model where `x` and `y` are your samples and labels respectively, you cannot compute cost without providing them.

If you have the following code:

```
predictions = ...
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_output, y_train))
cost = tf.Print(cost, [tf.shape(cost)], message='cost:')
```

Trying to evaluate it without providing placeholder values won't work:

```
sess.run(cost)
# error, no placeholder provided
```

However this will work as expected:

```
sess.run(cost, {x: x_train, y: y_train})
```

Regarding your first code fragment. In order to work, `tf.Print` node needs to be executed in order to print a message. I suspect in your case the print node is not used during further computations.

For example the following code won't produce output:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable([1., 2., 3])
b = tf.Variable([1., 2., 3])

c = tf.add(a, b)

# we create a print node, but it is never used
a = tf.Print(a, [tf.shape(a)], message='a.shape: ')

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(c))
```

However if you reverse lines such that the print node is used during computations, you will see the output:

```
a = tf.Print(a, [tf.shape(a)], message='a.shape: ')
# now c depends on the tf.Print node
c = tf.add(a, b)
```